# Appearance of nested lists converted to nested menu vs. form select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 types of select menus in jquery and jquery-ui: (a) ordinary form option select and (b) nested lists converted to menu via the menu( ) method. Type (a) is not nested and type (b) is nested (obviously). This is what I have in mind:

Type (a) html

```
<form action='#'>
    <fieldset>
        <select name='myselect' class='myselect'>
            <option value='x'>x</option>
            <option value='y'>y</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Type (a) jquery

```
$( ".myselect" ).selectmenu({ select: function( ){ ... } });
```

Type (b) html

```
<ul class='mymenu'>
    <li>
        <div>Label 1</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Label 1.1</div></li>
            <li><div>Label 1.2</div></li>
            <li><div>Label 1.3</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div>Label 1.3.1</div></li>
                    <li><div>Label 1.3.2</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Type (b) jquery

```
$( '.mymenu' ).menu({ select: function( ){ ... } });
```

You'll notice that the visual appearance of these 2 things is not the same although the nested list has only 1 top level element, so in principle they could look the same.

How can I make a nested select menu, type (b) above, with only one top level element look the same (via some css I guess) as the ordinary select menu? So the goal is to have ordinary select menu appearance but with nested menus.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to align the items vertically just remove margin and padding or adjust them to suit

```css
.mymenu, .mymenu li, .mymenu ul{margin:0; padding:0}
.mymenu li{list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul class='mymenu'>
    <li>
        <div>Label 1</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>Label 1.1</div></li>
            <li><div>Label 1.2</div></li>
            <li><div>Label 1.3</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div>Label 1.3.1</div></li>
                    <li><div>Label 1.3.2</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The goal is to have the form select menu appearance. So what css do I need to add? The form select menu has a little arrow pointing downwards, etc, lots of styling actually. Seems hard to replicate but maybe there is a way.